# Laravel 4 - Use Workbench User Model for Authentication

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a workbench, with a user model like this:

```
<?php
namespace package\vendor\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class CoreUser extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
}
```

Now I need to use this `CoreUser` as User Model for Authentication in `app/configs/auth.php`.

```
<?php

return array(
    'model' => 'package/vendor/Models/CoreUser',
)
```

But it seems I've set wrong value for `model` because I get this error:

```
Class '\package/vendor/Models/CoreUser' not found
```

How should I set `model` attribute for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Package\Models;

class CoreUser extends \User  {
   ...
}
```

Then access it in other classes with:

```
use Vendor\Package\Models\User as User;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced `/` with `\` and everything is fine now.

```
return array(
    'model' => 'package\vendor\Models\CoreUser',
)
```